# how to get table data from VIEW and then insert it into collection in MODEL ?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I want to make an ASP.NET application in MVC 4. At first,i have two tables (Category & Barber) which have many to many relationship.For each Barber,there will be more than one categories and for every Barber, list of categories may be different and I want to give it to my model  when I submit those from my "cshtml" and then i will do the rest.How can i do it?

Comment: Have you studied or tried before asking?

Comment: build and populate an array with the same structure as your model using jquery